# What are strategies for beating the PvP update challenge maps in Magicka?

Tags: magicka

I'm having a lot of trouble with the new challenge arenas that were introduced with the PvP update in Magicka.  I got the Final Frontier DLC and am trying to beat the Vulcan arena (though I'm assuming this question applies to all of the new arenas); however, I can only manage to get to the second or third wave each time.

I believe my problem is that against enemies in other challenge maps (and in adventure mode), it is a good strategy to play defensively.  However, the enemies in the new challenge maps cast high powered spells very often, more frequently than I can defend against with shields.

Are there any good strategies for being successful in the new challenge arenas?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest to find a friend that can help you. We successfully completed the Volcano challenge in two, after many attempts, but I failed alone.

Try to play defensive during the initial waves, create walls/barriers to block enemies and resistance auras like SAFE (Shield+Arcane+Fire+Electricity)

The key is to wait that chests drop the summon Magics: [Raise Dead](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Summon_Elemental) and [Summon Elemental](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Raise_Dead). This two spells are probably overpowered but very effective: when you get those spam them and the monsters will distract and hurt enemies. Remember to rebuild your protections and you should be able to complete the challenge.

In the next days we will try to complete the challenge without summon spells, and if we succeed I will update my answer.

Comment: I like your suggestion about SAFE, I don't usually use shields of more than one element but that seems to cover the most damaging ones. I find that Raise Dead is useful at early levels but looses effectiveness as you get to higher waves. However, I agree with you that summon elemental would be very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I played Magicka was long ago, but as I recall, I have 450 hours in that game.

The tips would be the same as you would use against any spellcasters, except for your enemies being far more dumb.

1. Nullify to make them lose their prepared spells and buffs. Notify your friends, though, if not playing alone.
2. Aforementioned, but overpowered Summon Elemental spells.
3. Napalm. Combines well with fire elementals.
4. Lightning bolts are instant deaths if cast after Nullify -- your enemies will have no shield.
5. QR-QR-A-S-E, enchanted on a weapon, cast after Nullify... Instawipe. Don't get yourself caught, though.

Whatever you use -- be fast. That's the core thing with Magicka. You may even train some spells to be cast almost instantly, as fast as the game allows the elements to be added to the bar. If you train yourself to cast the most important spells/magicks that way, you basically mastered Magicka.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was simply move left to right and spam spells.